# how do you know if this patent is design or utility, as no marking is mentioned on the patent?

Tags: design-patent, utility, utility-patent

how do you know if patent is design or utility, as no marking is mentioned on the patent?

Comment: Which country? It is marked on the patent, but differs by countries.

Comment: Can you provide the patent number? For US patents, it should be abundantly clear from the patent document.

Comment: USA, this is the patent number US20150090676A1

Comment: the patent does not mention either design or utility

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways.

For one, US design patents have a USD number, for example USD543181:

https://patents.google.com/patent/USD543181S1/en?oq=USD543181

In google it also says "US Design Grant".

The [USPTO page](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect2=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&d=PALL&RefSrch=yes&Query=PN/D543181) is a little harder, though

> CLAIM The ornamental design for a folder-type cellular phone with digital camera, as shown and described.

in combination with only figures and no description is a good hint.

Or if you look at the [pdf](http://pdfpiw.uspto.gov/.piw?Docid=D0543181&homeurl=http%3A%2F%2Fpatft.uspto.gov%2Fnetacgi%2Fnph-Parser%3FSect2%3DPTO1%2526Sect2%3DHITOFF%2526p%3D1%2526u%3D%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html%2526r%3D1%2526f%3DG%2526l%3D50%2526d%3DPALL%2526S1%3DD543181.PN.%2526OS%3DPN%2FD543181%2526RS%3DPN%2FD543181&PageNum=&Rtype=&SectionNum=&idkey=NONE&Input=View%20first%20page), it says "United States Design Patent".

While [your example](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/d1/56/02/b74a96bfb0de03/US20150090676A1.pdf) does not say so and that's how you know it's a "normal" patent.